# How to rename files having numeric suffix through a batch file

Tags: c, windows, file-rename, batch-rename

I have a legacy program that creates filenames as `<Common Prefix>_<Number>.dat` and puts them in a list in ascending order as below:

```
A2_132.dat
A2_184.dat
A2_24.dat
A2_362.dat
```

But, I need the files to be renamed in ascending order of numbers used as trailing names e.g. `132, 184, 24, 362` as in the order of their numeric values as `24, 132, 184, 362` so that I can have filename orderings as:

```
A2_24.dat
A2_132.dat
A2_184.dat
A2_362.dat
```

I think, the filenames need to be renamed as:

```
A2_024.dat
A2_132.dat
A2_184.dat
A2_362.dat
```

How can do it either through Windows batch program or a C program taking into account that I may have to go to all the subfolders recursively.
I don't want to change the legacy program for now to change the file generation and naming logic.

Comment: You choose first - C or Batch.  Ask for one or the other - or post two separate questions.

Comment: and both choices are poor choices if you ask me. Python is much more suitable for the job

Comment: You appear to be asking for a programming service rather than help with a specific programming issue.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre : Quite so; although he may be asking because those are the languages immediately available to him. I would not perhaps take the trouble install and learn Python for this trivial task, even if it were a more suitable tool for the job.

Comment: @clifford: that might be easier than learning to program in C.

Answer (score 0):

> misunderstood the recursive part so, only added in code...

So, if I understood well this question, maybe this code 'suit' to you:

```bat
@echo off & cd /d "%~dp0" 

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /r "%~dp0" %%R in (*.dat) do (

    set "_ren_it=%%~fR"
    set "_to_add_0=%%~nxR"

    for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=_" %%i in ('echo/!_to_add_0!') do (

        set _j=00%%j
        set "_File_Ren_=%%~i_!_j:~-7!"
        ren "!_ren_it!" !_File_Ren_!

    )
)
```